# Use agg method on only one level of Series with multiindex

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Let's start with a Series with a multiindex

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series(range(10), 
              index=[
                     [i//2 for i in range(10)],
                     [i%5 for i in range(10)]
])

s.index

>>> MultiIndex(levels=[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]],
               codes=[[0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4]])
```

If I want the minimum value at index level 0, I can simply write

```
s.min(level=0)
>>> 0    0
1    2
2    4
3    6
4    8
dtype: int64
```

Same for `max`, `min` `std`, etc

I even have the same result if I use `agg` with a single function, i.e `s.agg('min', level=0)` is equivalent to the previous command

However, it does not work if I pass a list of functions

```
s.agg(['min', 'max'], level=0)
>>>min    0
max    9
dtype: int64
```

Is there a way to specify the level as to have an output where both `min` and `max` are aggregated only following the first index ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible use extended form with `groupby`:

```
print (s.groupby(level=0).agg(['min', 'max']))
   min  max
0    0    1
1    2    3
2    4    5
3    6    7
4    8    9
```

Comment: Wow cool ! As my series was already the result of a `groupby.first` method I didn't think about using it again before agg. Will accept your answer as soon as I can :)